# Optimizing a diagonal elements of a matrix using cvxpy

Tags: python, numpy, cvxpy

If I have a diagonal matrix, its main diagonal elements are e**(1j*x) where x is the optimizable  variable between 0 and 2*pi, something like this: Matrix_of_X = np.diag(e**(1j*x))
How to use the CVX tool provided by python in this link: https://www.cvxpy.org/

for example the objective function is to maximize the trace of this diagonal matrix

it seems that this library accept only polynomial equations for x.

Comment: Please start by reading documentation, and perhaps some book about convex optimization, to see if you can reformulate your problem in convex form. From the information you provided seems that CVXPY is not the right tool for your problem.